# How can I count the number of some specific characters in a string recursively?

Tags: java

I was practicing recursion problem. there are some type of questions wants you to count the number of specific characters in a `String` without loop.

What kind of method should I use? can anyone explain to me?

Here is the question:"Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) the number of lowercase 'x' chars in the string."

my code:

```
public int countX(String str) {
    if(str.length()==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(str.charAt(0)=='x'){
        return 1+ countX(str.substring(1));
    }
    return countX(str);
}
```

Comment: Hey Allen, please check [ask] - we need to see some code alongside a more specific question.

Comment: So is there any issue with your code? What doesn't work? Do you get any error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but you need to revise the case where the first letter in `str` isn't `'x'`. What you are currently doing will cause infinite recursion because in the case where `str.charAt(0) != 'x'`, you recursively call `countX` on `str`. However, `str` is still the same string that didn't have `'x'` as its first letter, so it's going to call `countX` on `str` again and again and again, etc.. So the solution is to only call `countX` on `str.substring(1)` when its first letter isn't `'x'` like so,

```
public int countX(String str) {
    if(str.length()==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(str.charAt(0)=='x'){
        return 1 + countX(str.substring(1));
    }
    else{
        return countX(str.substring(1));
    }
}
```

**What your method was doing before**

Let's say I called `countX` on `"Hello"`, here's how the call stack trace would look like,

```
call countX("Hello")
"Hello".length() != 0 so we move on to the next condition
"Hello".charAt(0) != 'x' so we call countX("Hello")
    call countX("Hello")
    "Hello".length() != 0 so we move on to the next condition
    "Hello".charAt(0) != 'x' so we call countX("Hello")
        call countX("Hello")
        "Hello".length() != 0 so we move on to the next condition
        "Hello".charAt(0) != 'x' so we call countX("Hello");
            .
            .
            .
            infinite recursion
```

**What the new solution does**

```
call countX("Hello")
"Hello".length() != 0 so we move on to the next condition
"Hello".charAt(0) != 'x' so we call countX("ello")
    call countX("ello")
    "ello".length() != 0 so we move on to the next condition
    "ello".charAt(0) != 'x' so we call countX("llo")
        call countX("llo")
        "llo".length() != 0 so we move on to the next condition
        "llo".charAt(0) != 'x' so we call countX("lo");
            call countX("lo")
            "lo".length() != 0 so we move on to the next condition
            "lo".charAt(0) != 'x' so we call countX("o");
                call countX("o")
                "o".length() != 0 so we move on to the next condition
                "o".charAt(0) != 'x' so we call countX("");
                    call countX("")
                    "".length() == 0 so return 0
                return 0
            return 0
        return 0
    return 0
return 0
```

Notice how in the solution, we always have a way of getting to the base case (`str.length()==0`). Whereas before, there would be instances (when we encountered a letter that wasn't x) that would prevent the method from reaching the base case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot to `return` the method itself if the first `char` is not `x`.

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of method should I use? can anyone explain to me?

one solution is to use a `StringBuilder` and simply delete the first character at each invocation of the method, eventually, you'll get to the base case and should output the correct result.

```
public int countX(String str) {
       if(str.length() == 0) return 0;

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
       if(str.charAt(0) == 'x'){
           builder.deleteCharAt(0);
           return 1 + counter(builder.toString());
       }

       builder.deleteCharAt(0);
       return counter(builder.toString());   
 }
```

However, if you wish to proceed with your current solution, you'll need to replace this:

```
return countX(str);
```

with this:

```
return countX(str.substring(1));
```

the problem was that if the current character is not `'x'` you simply ignored it and didn't simplify the problem towards the base case.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your need. In below, you have the method you need to count recursively a character in a string.

```
 static int countCharRecursively(String str, char ch){

    if(str.indexOf(ch) != -1)
    {          
        return  countCharRecursively(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(ch)), ch)+ 
            countCharRecursively(str.substring(str.indexOf(ch)+1),ch) + 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is a complete program you can run.

```
public class CountCharRecursivelyInString{

 public static void main(String[] args){

    String str = "hello the world"; 

    char ch = 'l';

    int nbr = countCharRecursively(str, ch);

    System.out.println(ch + " : " + nbr);
}

static int countCharRecursively(String str, char ch){

    if(str.indexOf(ch) != -1)
    {          
        return  countCharRecursively(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(ch)), ch)+ 
            countCharRecursively(str.substring(str.indexOf(ch)+1),ch) + 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
 }
}
```